# Most efficient way to add one row and column to sparse scipy matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am using `scipy` sparse matrices with at most 4 nonzero elements in each row. I now need to expand them by adding a single row and column, then set the values of the elements in the new space. What is the most efficient way to do this? The original matrices are in `csc` format and they are non-trivial to construct, so instead of going back into the code that constructs them, I was hoping to find an easy way to graft on a new row and column. The matrices are rebuilt frequently, so resizing them and slicing in new values may be too slow.

Comment: `sparse.hstack` and `sparse.vstack` can add columns and rows to a matrix.  Under the covers they use `sparse.bmat` (look at their code).  `bmat` turns all inputs into `coo` format matrices, and joins their data/rows/cols attributes and makes a new `coo` format matrix (with further conversion if you want).

Comment: `csr/csc` has a `resize` method.  I haven't used it, but it looks it will efficiently increase the size (with apropriate tweak to the `indptr` attribute and shape).  You will though get a sparsity efficiency warning when you set the values of the new row or columns.  But since that's one time thing, I'd just ignore that.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, I think using `hstack` and `vstack` is probably the easiest, safest way to go. Conversions between `coo` and `csc` formats are linear-time operations and they're not slowing things down too much.